# Do weapons earn Freshness during a Splatfest?

Tags: splatoon-3

The [Freshness flag](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Freshness) is representative of that weapon's highest Freshness rating:

[image]

According to the wikia:

> If Fresh is reached with a weapon before dropping back down to Raw, it will still display the Fresh flag on the weapon select.

I played a lot with my Aerospray MG during the Splatfest, I also got the "30 Reefslider wins" so I definitely won a lot of battles, but my flag freshness is still at the lowest level, the grey flag.
I couldn't check my Flag freshness during the Splatfest, since that part of the screen is used to display the Splatfest rank.

So I'm wondering: do weapons actually earn Freshness during a Splatfest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fresh Flag is only affected by Regular Battles, so no, Splatfests do not count towards or against Fresh Flags.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out by myself.